# Where are filters on my range hood?

Tags: range

[image]

My Toronto, CA condo has [Sakura R727II range hood](http://www.sakura-canada.com/SakuraProduct1.html) ([Installation Guide](https://www.trailappliances.com/media/wysiwyg/PDFs/guides/Sakura_Hoodfans_09162013_R74730WII_2.pdf)) 
 and has

> - Twin sensor-loaded motors
> - Twin centrifugal turbo fans
> - Teflon-coated non-stick fan blades
> - Rear oil collectors

[This website](https://www.forumappliances.com/sakura-kitchen-range-hood-r727ii-30hs-30-stainless-steel/) says

> a thin aluminum filter traps grease even before reaching the fan blades

but where's filter?

[image]

Comment: From the shape it looks like the filters clip over the vane guards.

Comment: The aluminum mesh is the only filter.

Answer (score 1):

The website you linked to that sells the filters has this line in the description of the hood:

> ...a thin aluminum filter traps grease even before reaching the fan blades...

Based on the other diagrams of the product, the only place the filters can go is over the vane guards.  I guess there is a chance the filter sits right inside the vane guard, because the guard is described as "washable" as well, but that should be easy to determine once you have the filters.

Unless you do a lot of frying, the filters might not be necessary.  I assume that is why it is an optional accessory.