# Isn't range hood with filter top fan better?

Tags: range

My Toronto, CA condo has [Sakura R727II range hood](http://www.sakura-canada.com/SakuraProduct1.html) ([Installation Guide](https://www.trailappliances.com/media/wysiwyg/PDFs/guides/Sakura_Hoodfans_09162013_R74730WII_2.pdf)).

[image]

I saw [this an other Sakura range hood](https://www.forumappliances.com/sakura-kitchen-range-hood-b53-30hs-30-stainless-steel/) on Google Pictures. Please answer questions 1 and 2 in picture.

[image]

3. Isn't range hood with filters or slats better?

Fans and fan blades on my 727II are sooo greasy! Why 727II not have filters or slats? If it did, then fans and fan blades not so greasy?

Comment: Price differential? Depth? Available space to fit?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because opinion based

Comment: _"Why 727II not have filters or slats?"_ -- don't the accessories you describe in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/182548) answer that question? I.e. you _can_ install filters, if you're having trouble with grease (and probably should). Household hoods usually are smaller, have faster-running, noisier fans, and require some kind of filter (usually a sort of metal mesh) to keep grease out of the innards. But you can get certain models and brands that use slats (as in the second above), which use inertia instead of filters to grab the grease before it causes trouble. ...

Comment: ... These _generally_ use larger and/or slower-running fans, and can often be quieter, but in any case will generally have better air flow for a given amount of power, because the inertial filtering slows air flow less than a physical mesh would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slats are louvers which cover the entrance to the housing and prevent the blower from accidently ingesting things like paper towels or hands stuck up there. The small knobs on them are spring loaded levers which allow for removing the three panels for washing. Filters, in the sense of actually cleaning the air are uncommon because you wouldn't want a flammable substance like foam or paper catching grease. Instead there's usually some metal mesh or trap to catch grease which periodically needs cleaning.

In your particular case, the second model is superior. Grease is going to be mainly confined to the louvered panels which can be removed and chucked in the sink. (Possibly dishwasher if you're adventurous.) It probably also uses a blower rather than radial fan for higher airflow. I imagine the first is cheaper.

To answer your final question the fan is above the panels, but it's probably inside a large plastic baffle which reduces the rectangular opening down to a smaller round hole. It's along the same lines as a vacuum cleaner, which has a large square opening to clean with and a smaller round exhaust at the bag, with a fan in the middle. The difference being that the fan and exit in this case are still several inches in diameter. (The "fan" may be a centripetal blower too, to provide better airflow. Think leaf blower rather than desk fan.)

Incidentally, your existing fan also requires internal ducting because it can be installed with either top or back exhaust. The difference is that the fans are in the front of the ductwork.

Comment: How do you figure filters are uncommon? This is the first I hear of a range hood *without* a filter, not counting when it was lost by the previous owner. Mine has steel mesh filters which I throw in the dishwasher every 6 months or so, along with the removable fan cage. A quick wiping of the unit with soapy water and everything looks as good as new.

Comment: And one can get carbon filters to help with smells...

Comment: @Oliver Probably an oversight, I was thinking pleated paper filters rather than mesh screens. The one in the question also has an "aluminum filter" which I'd probably have called a trap, shield, or screen. I'll go back an edit it.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier that makes sense, and you probably do have the better terminology. That first one in the question looks like it won't trap much of anything though.